# ListData.svc: How to upload attachment?

Tags: 2010, javascript, rest, attachments, listdata.svc

How does one upload an attachment to a list item using JavaScript/HTL5 file upload API and the ListData.svc API?

I know I can do this using managed CSOM but I want to understand the SP 2010 REST API better. Currently I am getting the error:

> Invalid slug header for attachment. Slug headers must be of the form
>   "EntitySet,ItemId,Name"

If anyone knows of a resource they could point me to I would appreciate it!

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: No, I ended up using SPServices and then the SP 2013 REST API.

Comment: I think I'm having a related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195361/upload-file-to-sharepoint-2010-using-powershell-and-the-odata-api